# unable send pdf attachment in email generated from wicked-pdf in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email-attachments, wicked-pdf

I am trying to send the `pdf` as an `attachment` in the email. but getting an error.

`ctionView::MissingTemplate at /invoises/BRUqWOeEVNSN6GCwxQqLGg%253D%253D/send_invoice_email
Missing template invoises/#{invoise.id}/show_pdf_invoice.pdf.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :m`

i am using `wicked_pdf` gem.trying to generate the `pdf` from `html` `view`

method in `controller`

```
  def send_invoice_email
    CompanyMailer.invoice(@invoise.id).deliver
    redirect_to invoices_path, notice: 'Invoice Sent successfully.' 
  end
```

logic in `mailer`:

```
def invoice(invoice)
  invoice = Invoice.find(invoice)
  attachments["invoice.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(:pdf => "invoice",:template => 'invoices/#{invoice.id}/show_pdf_invoice.pdf.erb')
  )

  mail(to: "abc@gmail.com", subject: 'Your todo PDF is attached')
end
```

method in `controller`

```
  def show_pdf_invoice
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => false }
      format.pdf do
    render pdf: "show_pdf_invoice"
    #render :pdf => "pdf"#, :layout => 'pdf.html.erb'
      end
    end
  end
```

and in `invoices/show_pdf_invoice.pdf.erb`

```
  <h1>this is pdf invoice.<h1>
```

and in `company_mailer/invoice.html.erb`

```
  please find attached pdf.
```

Comment: not overly familiar with how `render_to_string` works but it looks like you have your string interpolation incorrectly set up. change to `"invoices/#{invoice.id}/show_pdf_invoice.pdf.erb"` use double quotes as the outermost quotes for string interpolation.

Comment: i changed that line. still the same error.

Comment: change to `render_to_string(template: 'invoices/show_pdf_invoice.pdf.erb')`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed. i need not to pass id in the url. i need to pass only `render_to_string(template: 'invoices/show_pdf_invoice.pdf.erb')`